# Пунктуация в предложениях с «Что значит»

Tags: пунктуация, цитата

После «что значит» идёт двоеточие и/или кавычки, если говорящий цитирует слова другого человека? Вот так: 
Что значит ненависть — неподходящее слово? 
Какая пунктуация в данном предложении, если учитывать, что слова, идущие после «что значит», — цитата? Или ничего и вовсе не нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что пишет Д. Э. Розенталь ([Знаки препинания при диалоге](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=160)).

Если в последующей реплике повторяются слова из предыдущей реплики, принадлежащей другому лицу, причем они воспринимаются как чужой текст, то эти слова выделяются кавычками:

1. Купавина. *Ах, это смешно наконец. Зачем юристом, когда **ничего** нет.*
   Лыняев. *Как **«ничего»**?*
2. *«Если вы **будете свободны**, заходите ко мне». — «Как это **“будете свободны”**? Ведь у меня каждая минута на учёте»*.

Если Вы дословно цитируете чьи-то слова, то их необходимо взять в кавычки. Двоеточие в этом случае не ставится, потому что слов "говорения" нет, а сама цитата является частью предложения, вписывается в него. Вопросительный знак ставится после кавычек.

Вот возможный диалог.
— Я считаю, что ненависть — неподходящее слово. Странно ты рассуждаешь.
— Что значит «ненависть — неподходящее слово»?